# C# Returning custom class Array

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a custom class defined:

```
class Car
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public string c;

    public static void GetCar()
    {
        var car = new Car[4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        {
            novica[i]= new Novica();
            novica[i].a="abc";
            novica[i].b="abc";
            novica[i].c="abc";
        }

    }
}
```

This fills the array with values, and now I would like to use this array with the values it gets (loading string from HTML) in a function that is not part of this class. Is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: You need to be more elaborate in specifying what you want.

Comment: I imagine you actually want `car[i] = new Novica();` etc.

Comment: Sorry about novica - it's supposed to be car there. Copy and paste:D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use it elsewhere, you would need to return the array from your function, like so:

```
public static Car[] GetCar()
    {
        var car = new Car[4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        {
            car[i]= new Novica();
            car[i].a="abc";
            car[i].b="abc";
            car[i].c="abc";
        }

        return car;
    }
```

Comment: This looks right.  I think he wants to return `novica` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your method doesn't actually return anything.

If you were to change the method signature to return the array the method creates:

```
public static Car[] GetCar()
{
    // Body

    return car;
}
```

The call would become as simple as:

```
var cars = Car.GetCar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slightly different construction. Provide an array containing all cars as static property

```
public class Car
{
    public static Car[] AllCars { get; private set; }

    public Car()
    {
        // Class and constructor somewhat simplyfied.
        AllCars = new Car[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            AllCars[i] = new Novica();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can work with cars like this

```
foreach (Car car in Car.AllCars) {
    // do something with car
}
```

Or access a specific car with

```
string a = Car.AllCars[i].a;
```